# What's the name of a function with a variable in the base and exponent?

Tags: functions, terminology

For example, $k^x$, where $k$ is a constant, is an exponential function. It is differentiated quite easily.

$x^x$ is also an exponential function. It takes much more effort to differentiate it.

Is there a specific name for the latter type of function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^x$ is an example of [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration). It is an exponential function, but involves *repeated exponentiation* as opposed to repeated multiplication.

Comment: I thought tetration was $x^x^x$ x times?

Comment: x^x^x^... *n* times, n can equal x